# Concat changes the category type to object / float64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

If I am reading just a piece of csv I get the following data structure

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 100000 entries, (2015-11-01 00:00:00, 4980770) to (2016-06-01 00:00:00, 8850573)
Data columns (total 5 columns):
CHANNEL          100000 non-null category
MCC              92660 non-null category
DOMESTIC_FLAG    100000 non-null category
AMOUNT           100000 non-null float32
CNT              100000 non-null uint8
dtypes: category(3), float32(1), uint8(1)
memory usage: 1.9+ MB
```

If I am reading the whole csv and concat the blocks as per above I get the following structure:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 30345312 entries, (2015-11-01 00:00:00, 4980770) to (2015-08-01 00:00:00, 88838)
Data columns (total 5 columns):
CHANNEL          object
MCC              float64
DOMESTIC_FLAG    category
AMOUNT           float32
CNT              uint8
dtypes: category(1), float32(1), float64(1), object(1), uint8(1)
memory usage: 784.6+ MB
```

Why are categorical variables changed to object / float64? How can I avoid this type change? Esp. the float64

This is the concatenation code:

```
df = pd.concat([process(chunk) for chunk in reader])
```

process function is just doing some cleaning and type assignments

Comment: can you post the code you use to load and concat it?

Comment: Categoricals also have problems with `NaN` sometimes

Comment: added to the text

Comment: for now I have a work-around where I explicitly re-cast all columns after the concat

Comment: You could use union_categorical in theory, but it's a bit of a pain here b/c you'd need to do it on the fly.  It would save memory, but at the cost of more complicated code.  See here for a simpler case:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639350/retaining-categorical-dtype-upon-dataframe-concatenation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following sample DataFrames:

```
In [93]: df1
Out[93]:
   A  B
0  a  a
1  b  b
2  c  c
3  a  a

In [94]: df2
Out[94]:
   A  B
0  b  b
1  c  c
2  d  d
3  e  e

In [95]: df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    4 non-null object
B    4 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), object(1)
memory usage: 140.0+ bytes

In [96]: df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    4 non-null object
B    4 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), object(1)
memory usage: 148.0+ bytes
```

NOTE: these two DFs have different categories:

```
In [97]: df1.B.cat.categories
Out[97]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

In [98]: df2.B.cat.categories
Out[98]: Index(['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype='object')
```

when we concatenate them Pandas won't merge categories - it'll create an `object` column:

```
In [99]: m = pd.concat([df1, df2])

In [100]: m.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    8 non-null object
B    8 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes
```

But if we concatenate two DFs with the same categories - everything works as expected:

```
In [102]: m = pd.concat([df1.sample(frac=.5), df1.sample(frac=.5)])

In [103]: m
Out[103]:
   A  B
3  a  a
0  a  a
3  a  a
2  c  c

In [104]: m.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4 entries, 3 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A    4 non-null object
B    4 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), object(1)
memory usage: 92.0+ bytes
```

Comment: @snovik, AFAIK currently it's the way to go